# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic

I've got a bit of dynamic SQL I'm running that is working fine when I manually write in the variables, but as soon as I then change them from the manually written in to actual variables, I get the error above.

The code is:

```
set @query = 'SELECT eng, ' + @colsNull + ' 
        from 
        (
            select eng, [count], cast(weekof as date) weekof
            from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK (''1 jan 2013'', ''9 apr 2013'', ''1 jan 2013'', ''9 apr 2013'')
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum([count])
            for weekof in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '
```

Which works fine, but as soon as I change it to

```
set @query = 'SELECT eng, ' + @colsNull + ' 
        from 
        (
            select eng, [count], cast(weekof as date) weekof
            from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK ('+@from+', '+@to+', '+@start+', '+@end+')
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum([count])
            for weekof in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '
```

I get the error.  I've also tried

```
set @query = 'SELECT eng, ' + @colsNull + ' 
        from 
        (
            select eng, [count], cast(weekof as date) weekof
            from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK ((select CONVERT(DATE'+@from+',105)), (select CONVERT(DATE'+@to+',105)), (select CONVERT(DATE'+@start+',105)), (select CONVERT(DATE'+@end+',105)))
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum([count])
            for weekof in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '
```

But to no avail!

Have also tried

```
from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK ((select CONVERT(DATE'''+@from+''',105)), (select CONVERT(DATE'''+@to+''',105)), (select CONVERT(DATE'''+@start+''',105)), (select CONVERT(DATE'''+@end+''',105)))
```

and

```
from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK ('''+@from+''', '''+@to+''', '''+@start+''', '''+@end+''')
```

Comment: Not enough single quotes in this bit `from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK ('+@from+', '+@to+', '+@start+', '+@end+')` I think.

Comment: @Dommer isn't that exactly what I put in the middle block of code?

Comment: I've now also tried 
    from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK ('''+@from+''', '''+@to+''', '''+@start+''', '''+@end+''') 
but no joy!

Comment: Yes it is, I was saying that bit was wrong. I have posted an answer which should help (I hope) :-)

Comment: What is the format of the date that you are passing in?  Is it `1 jan 2013`?

Comment: Yes - 
`   @From DATETIME,
    @To DATETIME,
    @start datetime,
    @end datetime
    set @From = '1 jan 2013'
    set @To = '9 apr 2013'
    set @start = '1 jan 2013'
    set @end = '9 apr 2013'`

Comment: If they are @DATETIME that's not the same thing. Hang on, I will update my answer...

Comment: I'm confused on this syntax. `Select * from table (date1,date2,date3,date4)` seems odd to me. Is there a missing `where` keyword? What is this list of dates supposed to be doing?

Comment: I think it's a function rather than a table

Comment: @Brad it's a function and the dates are the input!  Dommer has sorted it for me, however!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `@from` is a string like this: `1 jan 2013` then

What happens if you change this bit:

```
from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK ('+@from+', '+@to+', '+@start+', '+@end+')
```

to this:

```
from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK ('''+@from+''', '''+@to+''', '''+@start+''', '''+@end+''')
```

That's three single quotes in each position.

And if @from is a `DATETIME` which you need in the format `'d mmm yyyy'` then you could try this for each date:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, @from, 106)
```

So the whole thing ends up like this:

```
set @query = 'SELECT eng, ' + @colsNull + ' 
        from 
        (
            select eng, [count], cast(weekof as date) weekof
            from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK (''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @from, 106) + ''', ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @to, 106) + ''', ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @start, 106) + ''')
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum([count])
            for weekof in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '
```

Comment: So `    from dbo.RPT_ENG_WEEK (CONVERT(VARCHAR,('''+@from+''',106) ` etc?

Comment: Awesome - that works brilliantly!  Had forgotten that everything needs to be in a string to work!  This may be my last voyage into dynamic SQL for a while...!